# How to change visibility of a textbox if any of checkbox selected in checkboxlist wpf?

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox

My objective is to control the visibility of a textbox when any of check box selected in a listbox of check boxes.

Here is what I have tried so far

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding IssueTypes}" Name="lbModules"  VerticalAlignment="Top">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <CheckBox 
                Content="{Binding IssueName}" 
                x:Name="chkModules" Margin="0,5,0,0" 
                />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>

<RichTextBox 
    x:Name="txtIssueDescription" 
    Width="Auto" 
    MinHeight="60"  
    Visibility="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=chkModules, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}"
    >
</RichTextBox>
```

Comment: Are you able to add a backing property for the checkbox to the class that IssueTypes is a collection of?

Comment: IssueTypes is a collection of IsueName

Comment: Your problem here is that when you have more than one item in `IssueTypes`, you'll also have more than one CheckBox with the name `chkModules`.

Comment: Yeah I got it..How can I resolve the issue?

Comment: If you found my answer helpful please vote for it or mark it as useful. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Refer the below code.

```
<Window x:Class="ChkList_Learning.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ChkList_Learning"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Window.Resources>
    <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BoolToVis"/>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <StackPanel>
        <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding IssueTypes}" Name="lbModules"  VerticalAlignment="Top">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <CheckBox Content="{Binding IssueName}" IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}" x:Name="chkModules" Margin="0,5,0,0" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
        <RichTextBox x:Name="txtIssueDescription" Width="Auto" MinHeight="60"  Visibility="{Binding IsVisible, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVis}}"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace ChkList_Learning
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.DataContext = new ViewModel();
        }
    }

    class ViewModel:INotifyPropertyChanged  
    {
        public ObservableCollection<IssueType> IssueTypes { get; set; }

        public bool IsVisible
        {
            get { return IssueTypes.Any(x=>x.IsChecked); }
        }

        public ViewModel()
        {
            IssueTypes = new ObservableCollection<IssueType>();
            IssueTypes.CollectionChanged += IssueTypes_CollectionChanged;
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                IssueTypes.Add(new IssueType() { IssueName = "IssueName"+i });
            }
        }

        private void IssueTypes_CollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.OldItems != null)
            {
                foreach (IssueType item in e.OldItems)
                    item.PropertyChanged -= new
                                           PropertyChangedEventHandler(item_PropertyChanged);
            }

            if (e.NewItems != null)
            {
                foreach (INotifyPropertyChanged item in e.NewItems)
                {
                    if (item != null)
                    {
                        item.PropertyChanged +=
                        new PropertyChangedEventHandler(item_PropertyChanged);
                    }
                }

            }
        }

        private void item_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.PropertyName == "IsChecked")
            {
                OnPropertyChanged("IsVisible");
            }
        }


        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    class IssueType:INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private string issueName;

        public string IssueName
        {
            get { return issueName; }

            set
            {
                issueName = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
        private bool isChecked;

        public bool IsChecked
        {
            get { return isChecked; }

            set
            {
                isChecked = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }   

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would make a view model class for IssueTypes. I'm assuming IssueName is just a string here.

```
public class IssueType
{
    public string IssueName { get; set; }
    public bool IsChecked { get; set; }
}
```

In your code behind try having something like

```
private void chkModules_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
        IsChecked = IssuesTypes.Any(it => it.IsChecked);
}

private bool isChecked;

public bool IsChecked
{
    get { return isChecked; }
    set
    {
        if (isChecked != value)
        {
            isChecked = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("IsChecked");
        }
    }
}
```

Then in your xaml make sure the event is added to the checkbox:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding IssueTypes}" Name="lbModules"  VerticalAlignment="Top">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <CheckBox 
        Content="{Binding IssueName}"
        Checked="chkModules_Checked"
        x:Name="chkModules" Margin="0,5,0,0" 
        />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```